# I do not succeed installing anything with pip2.7 in mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, pip

All is already said in the title. I spent already a few hours to read and try working around without success, this is why I ask now here.

```
$ pip2.7 install numpy
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement numpy
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for numpy
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/servoz/.pip/pip.log

[servoz@irmu06]:~ $ more /Users/servoz/.pip/pip.log
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: timed out
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/ when looking for download links for numpy
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for numpy
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for numpy:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: timed out
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/ when looking for download links for numpy
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement numpy
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /private/var/folders/H8/H8pQdhk6FqiNDBM7G4Q13k++-KY/-Tmp-/pip_build_econdami...
No distributions at all found for numpy
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for numpy
```

The problem does not seem to come from connexion to pypi.python.org:

```
$ ping pypi.python.org
PING python.map.fastly.net (185.31.17.223): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 185.31.17.223: icmp_seq=0 ttl=51 time=27.198 ms
64 bytes from 185.31.17.223: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=27.130 ms
64 bytes from 185.31.17.223: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=27.144 ms
64 bytes from 185.31.17.223: icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=27.237 ms
64 bytes from 185.31.17.223: icmp_seq=4 ttl=49 time=27.126 ms
64 bytes from 185.31.17.223: icmp_seq=5 ttl=49 time=27.100 ms
64 bytes from 185.31.17.223: icmp_seq=6 ttl=51 time=27.092 ms
64 bytes from 185.31.17.223: icmp_seq=7 ttl=49 time=27.185 ms
^C
--- python.map.fastly.net ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 27.092/27.151/27.237/0.047 ms
```

It works on linux and I confess I do not know very well mac OS X.
Any suggestion will be very appreciated!
Thank you by advance!

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but you're better off using a package manager for something with a lot of C like NumPy (homebrew or MacPorts).

Comment: The system Python already has NumPy installed. It is better I guess to not replace the system version with something else (possible incompatibilities). Your best bet is again to use a package manager and to work with the Python provided by the package manager.

Comment: This is curious: `Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: timed out` -- does `curl -I https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/` succeed? If not, that's a problem to trace.

Comment: @EOL, in my opinion using `virtualenv` or `anaconda` is a much better way than trying to make `homebrew` or `MacPorts` work. If the pinging works, that could be a `ssl` problem in python.

Comment: @ Paul Bissex: $ curl -I https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Comment: @ EOL about Numpy already installed : [servoz@irmu06]:~ $ python
Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy

Comment: @EOL: I do not know mac OS. I work with Linux. I wrote tools with python under Linux. I want now install this tools on other computer of my team. I just started on a mac. In fact I have no idea of what is the best way to do it ... I trust you if you say it is better to use a package manager, but ... please, can you give me the best direction to do it on mac OS X!!!

Comment: one other idea. Do you think that this problem could come from the proxy ?

Comment: I am now convinced that the problem comes from a connect problem ... But I do not where to look for. For me the network is well configured ... I confess that I am a little lost : curl -vfsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install
* About to connect() to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 185.31.17.133... Operation timed out
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Comment: @cel There is really no "trying to make (…) MacPorts work": it works by itself! I do not know about Anaconda in particular, but out-of-package-manager installs often install things in places that are incompatible with package managers: when you want to add, say, Python modules that are not in such installs, it is often much easier to go through a package manager (compilations,…), but then you cannot use your original install and the package manager at the same time (different Python interpreters). So, the question is how Anaconda meshes with homebrew or MacPorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok  I understood,

In fact, the problem came from the proxy (thanks to Paul Bissex that gave me the good idea to check the connexion with curl -I pypi.python.org/simple/numpy).
So I added these 2 lines in /etc/profile (to permit for everybody):

```
export http_proxy=http://server-ip:port/
export https_proxy=http://server-ip:port/
```

see for exemple: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-proxy-environment-variable/

Now the connexion problem is fixed :

```
$ curl -I https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 17 Mar 2015 11:18:19 GMT
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-PYPI-LAST-SERIAL: 1443843
Cache-Control: max-age=600, public
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Public-Key-Pins: max-age=600; includeSubDomains; pin-sha256="WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18="; pin-sha256="5C8kvU039KouVrl52D0eZSGf4Onjo4Khs8tmyTlV3nU="; pin-sha256="5C8kvU039KouVrl52D0eZSGf4Onjo4Khs8tmyTlV3nU="; pin-sha256="lCppFqbkrlJ3EcVFAkeip0+44VaoJUymbnOaEUk7tEU="; pin-sha256="TUDnr0MEoJ3of7+YliBMBVFB4/gJsv5zO7IxD9+YoWI="; pin-sha256="x4QzPSC810K5/cMjb05Qm4k3Bw5zBn4lTdO/nEW/Td4=";
Via: 1.1 varnish
Content-Length: 15747
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 51777
X-Served-By: cache-iad2134-IAD, cache-fra1220-FRA
X-Cache: HIT, HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1, 17
X-Timer: S1426591099.867129,VS0,VE0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

and:

```
$ pip2.7 install numpy
Downloading/unpacking numpy
Downloading numpy-1.9.2-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (3.7MB) downloaded
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy
Cleaning up...
```

Thanks to all for help.